# javascript add a click event to an underlayered element

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I'm learning javascript and I've faced with a strange case while doing [the gallery](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Image_gallery) example in the MDN. I decided to add a simple function to this example but it didn't work. My goal is to add a function to the ".displayed-img" img.

I know that the issue is because of the "overlay" div. and I can run my function when I comment that line in the HTML. But I wonder what would be the best approach when I have a case like this and I need to access to an object which sits beneath another one. Thanks.

Here is my code:

```js
var displayedImage = document.querySelector('.displayed-img');
var thumbBar = document.querySelector('.thumb-bar');

var btn = document.querySelector('button');
var overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');
var imgUrl, currentImgUrl;
/* Looping through images */
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  imgUrl = 'https://via.placeholder.com/640x48'+(i+1)+'.jpg';
  var newImage = document.createElement('img');
  newImage.setAttribute('src', imgUrl);
  thumbBar.appendChild(newImage);

  newImage.addEventListener ('click', function(e){
    displayedImage.setAttribute('src', e.target.getAttribute('src'));
  } );

}

displayedImage.addEventListener('click', sayHi);

function sayHi(){
  console.log('hi');
}


btn.onclick = function() {
  if (btn.getAttribute('class')==='dark') {
    overlay.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)';
    btn.textContent = 'Light';
    btn.setAttribute('class', 'light');

  } else {
    overlay.style.backgroundColor =  'rgba(0,0,0,0)';
    btn.textContent = 'Darken';
    btn.setAttribute('class', 'dark');
  }

}
```

```css
body {
  width: 640px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.full-img {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 640px;
  height: 480px;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 640px;
  height: 480px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

button {
  border: 0;
  background: rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.6);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px white;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
}

.thumb-bar img {
  display: block;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Image gallery</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Image gallery example</h1>

    <div class="full-img">
      <img class="displayed-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/640x480">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <button class="dark">Darken</button>
    </div>

    <div class="thumb-bar">


    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please update the snippet I made with enough relevant script and pictures from https://placeholder.com for example to make a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks for your edit. I've fixed those areas and would follow the same in my future posts.